# RobotFramework Monitoring Thread to Trigger Teardown

Tags: multithreading, robotframework

I am trying to have a monitoring thread in robotframework to continuously monitor a signal and force a teardown if a certain signal is read. I have the following code.

```
import signal
from datetime import datetime
from robot.api import logger
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
import logging
import thread
import os
import sys
import time


def do_error_log_monitoring_new():
    def _monitor_log():
        time.sleep(5)
        # Monitor_Some_Signal
        builtin_lib.fatal_error(msg='Force Teardown')

    thread_logger = logging.getLogger('root')
    thread_logger.info("Started Fault Listener")
    builtin_lib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('BuiltIn', all=True)
    thread.start_new_thread(_monitor_log, ())
```

I have `builtin_lib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('BuiltIn', all=True)` with the `all=True` argument to return dictionary mapping of all library names to instances. However I see the following error:

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'fatal_error'

Furthermore, removing the `all=True` argument allows the function to go through and fatal_error to trigger, however I notice that it does not trigger a teardown in the main thread, which is what I intend to do. Any advice on how I can trigger teardown in the main thread from the `fatal_error()` function in the secondary thread?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `builtin_lib` to a dictionary (the result of `BuiltIn().get_library_instances(..., all=True)`. As the error message states, this dictionary does not have a `fatal_error` method.

Change this:

```
builtin_lib.fatal_error(msg='Force Teardown')
```

... to this:

```
BuiltIn().fatal_error(msg='Force Teardown')
```

If you only need a reference to the BuiltIn library (versus a dictionary of all libraries), you don't need to call `get_library_instance` at all since `BuiltIn()` already returns an instance of the library.

Comment: I was trying this earlier but I still can't seem to force a teardown in the main thread. The fatal_error in the second thread does not seem to force teardown in the main thread.